# How to I list all mongo databases in node using promises?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm having difficulty using promises with mongo, I simply want to connect and list all the databases, code is as follows:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// useUnifiedTopology is needed to hide a warning
MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(db => {
    console.log("Connected");
    return db.admin().listDataBases()
      .then(results => console.log(results))
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I am getting the error `db.admin` is not a function. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently, I was able to list the databases like this:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const client = new MongoClient(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true});

async function listDatabases() {
    const connection = await client.connect();
    const adminClient = connection.db().admin();
    const dbInfo = await adminClient.listDatabases();
    return dbInfo.databases;
}

(async () => {
    const databases = await listDatabases();
    console.log(databases);
})()
```

Basically you use the client to connect to the server, then call `db()` on the connection and get the `admin` object which allows you to finally read the databases.